# Which is more recommended, test classes or inline test functions?

Tags: apex, unit-test

So up until now every time I make an apex class, I make a separate class that tests that class (usually the same name with the suffix "TestClass"), which is what I've seen a lot of people do. However I am now aware that the same thing can be accomplished by annotating test functions inside the main class, instead of having a whole other class (which takes up space in the apex class list).

My question is whether there is a recommended way of doing this or is it literally just user preference? Personally I would prefer inline test methods as it just seems cleaner but are there any repercussions or implications that I should be aware of before changing all my code?

Comment: I thought test methods had to be in a separate class now since summer 13. Assuming your class is using API 28 or above that is.

Comment: Hmm, so it would appear :/ I thought otherwise considering some code generated by SF had inline tests in.

Comment: Maybe if it's using an older API

Comment: Also, I *think* that test methods in not-test classes count against your apex size, but class marked @isTest don't.

Comment: You used to have to do this to access private properties/methods when testing, but as part of API 28.0 the @TestVisible annotation means this is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of completeness I'll add my comment as an answer.

From Summer 13/API 28 and above test methods have to be in their own test class, using the @isTest annotation. As Dominic says this also has the benefit of not being included in the orgs apex character limit.